# set of keys for nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, set-comprehension

I have a couple lines to populate a `set`.

```
x = {1: {2: 4, 3: 6}, 5: {2:6, 10: 25, 14: 12}}

keys = set()
for y in x:
    for z in x[y]:
        keys.add(z)

# keys is now `set([2, 3, 10, 14])`
```

I can't shake the feeling that I can do this better, but nothing I come up with is seems great. Most implementations build a `list` first, which is annoying. There are lots of `x` in `y`, and most `y` have the same `z`.

```
# Builds a huuuuge list for large dicts.
# Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/241211
keys = set(itertools.chain(*x.values()))

# Still builds that big list, and hard to read as well.
# I wrote this one on my own, but it's pretty terrible.
keys = set(sum([x[y].keys() for y in x], []))

# Is this what I want?
# Finally got the terms in order from https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/241211
keys = {z for y in x for z in x[y]}
```

Is the original code the "most pythonic" or is one of the one-liners better? Something else?

Comment: I would say that approaches 1 (loop), 2 (set from chain which does **not** build a list), and 4 (nested set comprehension) are all valid, Pythonic and algorithmically sound. 3 (sum of lists) has quadratic time complexity and should be discarded. Which of the 3 you chose is a matter of taste and whether you like it readable, concise or C-optimized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use

```
{k for d in x.itervalues() for k in d}
```

`itervalues()` (just `values()` in Python 3) doesn't build a list, and this solution doesn't involve dictionary lookup (in contrast to `{z for y in x for z in x[y]}`).

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `itertools` module, specifically the `chain` class.

```
>>> x = {1: {2: 4, 3: 6}, 5: {2:6, 10: 25, 14: 12}}
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain.from_iterable(x.itervalues()))
set([2, 3, 10, 14])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `dict.items()`:

```
x = {1: {2: 4, 3: 6}, 5: {2:6, 10: 25, 14: 12}}
final_x = set(i for b in [b.keys() for i, b in x.items()] for i in b)
```

Output:

```
set([2, 3, 10, 14])
```

Comment: `dict.items()` in  Python 2 creates a list of dictionary items, which is something the OP wants to avoid. Then `[b.keys() for i, b in x.items()]` creates another list. In that list comprehension you call `dict.keys()`, which creates yet another list.